# CSS Card Flip isn't showing back face

Tags: css, css-transitions

I've set up a card flip feature where the user can see the back of a card, click and drag it, then click on a hot spot (black bar here) that will then flip the card over.

All of it works except the part where it shows the back of the card. The  flip animation happens, it's just blank.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Here's where I am...

[Here's a fiddle with functionality.](http://jsfiddle.net/johnlayne/gJaCP/1/)

HTML

```
<div id="flipStage">
    <div class="card" id="bsg">
        <div class="front" id="bsgFront"></div>
        <div class="back" id="bsgBack"></div>
        <div class="flipButton"></div>
        <div class="handle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.flipStage {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.card {
    cursor: pointer;
    height:175px;
    width:125px;
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .5s;
    -moz-transition: -moz-transform .5s;
    -o-transition: -o-transform .5s;
    transition: transform .5s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-perspective: 300px;
    -moz-perspective: 300px;
    -o-perspective: 300px;
    perspective: 300px;
}
.flipped {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
.card .front, .card .back {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden;
    -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
}
#bsg {
    top:150px;
    left:150px;
}
#bsgFront {
    background-image:url(http://images.penguinmagic.com/images/products/original/8006b.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
#bsgBack {
    background-image:url(http://images2.fanpop.com/image/photos/9400000/Tricia-Helfer-BSG-Promotional-Photography-tricia-helfer-9422601-1089-1450.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size: 100%;
}
.flipButton {
    height: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    background-color:black;
}
.handle {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 20px;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you are flipping the card. All of your content is on one side of the card.

Comment: I have my stage, the card, and then the front and back. Is that not the correct structure?

Comment: And your image won't come in right. here I'll post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gJaCP/3/

You need the initial state of back to be flipped 180.

```
.back {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

I added a bit of text so you can see it flipping. Try a different back image, because the one you are using redirects and I think isn't loading. In my link I used the front again.

I set BG to 50% just so you know it is indeed the back.

http://jsfiddle.net/gJaCP/4/

http://davidwalsh.name/css-flip

Comment: I changed the back to make it easier to see. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gJaCP/7/)

Comment: This is good progress, thank you! Now when I add a second card, I get some weird z-index thing going on in Safari! The card looks like it's flipping behind the other cards. [New Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/gJaCP/8/)

Comment: I'll start another discussion. Thanks, fellas.